# Accessing localhost over WiFi by name

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ubuntu-14.04

This is my configuration:
1. Ubuntu 14.04 LAMPP server (localhost).
2. WiFi Access Point on ubuntu server.
3. Android device connected to WiFi access point.

I can access localhost from android device by typing IP address of my localhost. 
How can I access just typing the name instead of IP address? (for example myserver directly in browser bar)?

Answer (score 0):

localhost cannot be accessed over a network because the IP [127.0.0.1] is parsed *before* the NIC. To quote [Wikipedia on localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost): "Such packets are never delivered to any network interface controller (NIC) or device driver, which permits testing of software in the absence of any hardware network interfaces."

[It is possible to give *localhost* a different IP address using the *hosts* file, which might be done for test purposes, but that would lead to issues if left in place.]